# как получить все значения после первого слеша из урлы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

получаю pathname

```
pathname: "/kids/dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki"
```

с помщью substr убераю первый слеш

```
location.pathname.substr(1,);
```

дальше получаю

```
kids/dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki
```

и теперь вопрос как мне взять все значення после первого слеша?
что бы я получи dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki ???

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `location.pathname = location.pathname.replace(/^\/?\w+\//, '')`

Comment: не подходит мне возвращает kids/dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki

Comment: случайно регулярку заключил в кавычки

Answer (score 0):

> и теперь вопрос как мне взять все значення после первого слеша? что бы я получи `dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki` ???

Попробуйте так

```js
const paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. It barked. /kids/dlya-malyshey/platya-i-yubki';
const regex = /\/(.*)/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
console.log(found[0].split('/'));
```